# Spark Noob confused by seeming inconsistency between DataFrame count() and show()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I noticed this while trying to load and clean a csv file with some rows not complying to the schema.
The following test case illustrates what I'm seeing.

test.csv:

```
ROWNUM,SOME_INT,SOME_STRING
1,12,aaa
2,NA,bbb
3,32,ccc
```

The second row won't comply with the schema because of that NA.

I loaded the file like this:

```
Using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{
     |     DataTypes, StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataTypes, StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType}

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> val dfSchema = StructType(
     |     StructField("ROWNUM", IntegerType, true)
     |     :: StructField("SOME_INT", IntegerType, false)
     |     :: StructField("SOME_STRING", StringType, false)
     |     :: Nil)
dfSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(ROWNUM,IntegerType,true), StructField(SOME_INT,IntegerType,false), StructField(SOME_STRING,StringType,false))

scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(dfSchema).load("/Users/user/test.csv")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ROWNUM: int, SOME_INT: int ... 1 more field]


scala> df.head(3)
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,12,aaa], [null,null,null], [3,32,ccc])
```

The second row has all nulls because "NA" is not an integer - fair enough.
But when I tried to detect / isolate the null rows I saw behaviour I didn't expect:

```
scala> val dfNullRows = df.filter(df.col("ROWNUM").isNull) // expecting 1 row
dfNullRows: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [ROWNUM: int, SOME_INT: int ... 1 more field]

scala> dfNullRows.count()
res2: Long = 0

scala> dfNullRows.show()
+------+--------+-----------+
|ROWNUM|SOME_INT|SOME_STRING|
+------+--------+-----------+
|  null|    null|       null|
+------+--------+-----------+

scala> val dfNonNullRows = df.filter(df.col("ROWNUM").isNotNull) // expecting 2 rows
dfNonNullRows: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [ROWNUM: int, SOME_INT: int ... 1 more field]

scala> dfNonNullRows.count()
res4: Long = 3

scala> dfNonNullRows.show()
+------+--------+-----------+
|ROWNUM|SOME_INT|SOME_STRING|
+------+--------+-----------+
|     1|      12|        aaa|
|     3|      32|        ccc|
+------+--------+-----------+

scala> val dfRow2 = df.filter(df.col("ROWNUM") === 2)  // expecting empty DataFrame
dfRow2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [ROWNUM: int, SOME_INT: int ... 1 more field]

scala> dfRow2.count()
res6: Long = 1

scala> dfRow2.show()
+------+--------+-----------+
|ROWNUM|SOME_INT|SOME_STRING|
+------+--------+-----------+
+------+--------+-----------+
```

show() is giving me what I expect in all three cases above, but count() does not seem to be consistent with that.

Am I making some invalid assumption about what's happening here?
It's almost as if count() is operating on a version of the dataframe(s) without the specified schema.

Comment: I could not find a source on this but I think you are right with your idea: count is optimized and does not perform the operations fully while show triggers an execution which checks for the schema. You could try to for the execution of your filters before calling count.

Comment: I noticed that because of my schema, `df` ended up with nulls in fields specified as non-nullable. I modified the schema to make all fields nullable. - made no difference.

Then I tried creating a second DataFrame using that same new schema `val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd,dfSchema)` and used that DataFrame instead of the original - filter / count / show now give the results I was expecting.